# JSON and PHP Error Occurred in registration- Android Studio

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

When ever I try to register a user, I get the below error and it does not insert the data into my database and table which is on localhost wamp server and the database is saved on phpMyAdmin, When I register a user I get the below error message which he occurs if user fails to register. I have four PHP files which are index.php where the error is coming from as it does not register the user on my phpMyAdmin database so no data gets entered into the database.

**Error Log**

> 07-23 15:23:10.833    2133-2395/com.bradvisor.bradvisor E/JSON﹕ No database selected
>       07-23 15:23:10.833    2133-2395/com.bradvisor.bradvisor E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value No of type
>   java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

PHP Files

**Index.PHP**

```
   <?php

/**
 PHP API for Login, Register, Changepassword, Resetpassword Requests and for Email Notifications.
 **/

if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
    // Get tag
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];

    // Include Database handler
    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    // response Array
    $response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);

    // check for tag type
    if ($tag == 'login') {
        // Request type is check Login
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // check for user
        $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
        if ($user != false) {
            // user found
            // echo json with success = 1
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["user"]["fname"] = $user["firstname"];
            $response["user"]["lname"] = $user["lastname"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["uname"] = $user["username"];
            $response["user"]["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];

            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user not found
            // echo json with error = 1
            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } 
  else if ($tag == 'chgpass'){
  $email = $_POST['email'];

  $newpassword = $_POST['newpas'];


  $hash = $db->hashSSHA($newpassword);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"];
  $subject = "Change Password Notification";
         $message = "Hello User,\n\nYour Password is sucessfully changed.\n\nRegards,\nBradVisor Team.";
          $from = "contact@BradVisor.com";
          $headers = "From:" . $from;
    if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {

 $user = $db->forgotPassword($email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
if ($user) {
         $response["success"] = 1;
          mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
         echo json_encode($response);
}
else {
$response["error"] = 1;
echo json_encode($response);
}


            // user is already existed - error response


        } 
           else {

            $response["error"] = 2;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User not exist";
             echo json_encode($response);

}
}
else if ($tag == 'forpass'){
$forgotpassword = $_POST['forgotpassword'];

$randomcode = $db->random_string();


$hash = $db->hashSSHA($randomcode);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"];
  $subject = "Password Recovery";
         $message = "Hello User,\n\nYour Password is sucessfully changed. Your new Password is $randomcode . Login with your new Password and change it in the User Panel.\n\nRegards,\nBradVisor Team.";
          $from = "contact@BradVisor.com";
          $headers = "From:" . $from;
    if ($db->isUserExisted($forgotpassword)) {

 $user = $db->forgotPassword($forgotpassword, $encrypted_password, $salt);
if ($user) {
         $response["success"] = 1;
          mail($forgotpassword,$subject,$message,$headers);
         echo json_encode($response);
}
else {
$response["error"] = 1;
echo json_encode($response);
}


            // user is already existed - error response


        } 
           else {

            $response["error"] = 2;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User not exist";
             echo json_encode($response);

}

}
else if ($tag == 'register') {
        // Request type is Register new user
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $uname = $_POST['uname'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];



        // check if user is already existed
                    // store user
            $user = $db->storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $uname, $password);
            if ($user) {
                // user stored successfully
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["user"]["fname"] = $user["firstname"];
            $response["user"]["lname"] = $user["lastname"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["uname"] = $user["username"];
            $response["user"]["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];

                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                // user failed to store
                $response["error"] = 1;
                $response["error_msg"] = "JSON Error occured in Registartion";
                echo json_encode($response);

        }
    } else {
         $response["error"] = 3;
         $response["error_msg"] = "JSON ERROR";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    echo "BradVisor Login API";
}
?>
```

**DB_Connect.php File**

```
<?php
class DB_Connect {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }

    // Connecting to database
    public function connect() {
        require_once 'include/config.php';
        // connecting to mysql
        $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        // selecting database
        mysqli_select_db($con, "DB_DATABASE");

     // return database handler
        return $con;
    }

    // Closing database connection
    public function close() {
        mysqli_close();
    }

}

?>
```

**UserFunction.PHP File**

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

    private $db;

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $db = new DB_Connect();
        $this->db = $db->connect();

    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }


    /**
     * Random string which is sent by mail to reset password
     */

public function random_string()
{
    $character_set_array = array();
    $character_set_array[] = array('count' => 7, 'characters' => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
    $character_set_array[] = array('count' => 1, 'characters' => '0123456789');
    $temp_array = array();
    foreach ($character_set_array as $character_set) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $character_set['count']; $i++) {
            $temp_array[] = $character_set['characters'][rand(0, strlen($character_set['characters']) - 1)];
        }
    }
    shuffle($temp_array);
    return implode('', $temp_array);
}


public function forgotPassword($forgotpassword, $newpassword, $salt){
    $result = mysqli_query($this->db, "UPDATE `users` SET `encrypted_password` = '$newpassword',`salt` = '$salt' 
                          WHERE `email` = '$forgotpassword'");

if ($result) {

return true;

}
else
{
return false;
}

}
/**
     * Adding new user to mysqli database
     * returns user details
     */

    public function storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $uname, $password) {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

    $result = mysqli_query($this->db,"INSERT INTO `users`(`uid`, `unique_id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `email`, `encrypted_password`, `salt`, `created_at`) VALUES('$uuid', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$uname', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");  
  // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            // get user details 
            $uid = mysqli_insert_id($this->db); // last inserted id
            $result = mysqli_query($this->db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
            // return user details
            return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verifies user by email and password
     */
    public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
        // check for result 
        $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $salt = $result['salt'];
            $encrypted_password = $result['encrypted_password'];
            $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
            // check for password equality
            if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $result;
            }
        } else {
            // user not found
            return false;
        }
    }


 /**
     * Check user is existed or not
     */
    public function isUserExisted($email) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->db, "SELECT email from users WHERE email = '$email'");
        $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            // user existed 
            return true;
        } else {
            // user not existed
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encrypting password
     * returns salt and encrypted password
     */
    public function hashSSHA($password) {

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypting password
     * returns hash string
     */
    public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

        return $hash;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: You should [display errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: I dont get no errors, I only get the below error. 7-23 14:31:04.836    2077-2228/com.bradvisor.bradvisor E/JSON﹕ {"tag":"register","success":0,"error":1,"error_msg":"JSON Error occured in Registartion"}

Comment: That's why you should use mysqli_* functions that display errors. Have a look at this for example: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: could you advise which line shall I put error message in,

Comment: I get a error of here  $result = mysqli_query($this->db, "INSERT INTO users SET (unique_id, firstname, lastname, email, username, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$uname', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");

Comment: You should do it each time you call `mysqli_query`. For this particular problem, it's probably somewhere in `DB_Functions::storeUser()` function.

Comment: Remove the `SET` keyword from your `INSERT` query.

Comment: could you advise how shall I put mysqli_error and which line or place shall I put this code in mysqli_error($this->db)

Comment: You already did it in `getUserByEmailAndPassword()` function (1st line), do the same. (The `or die(mysqli_error($this->db));` part.)

Comment: I am now trying this . or die(mysqli_error($this->db));

Comment: I have edited my error log. I am getting no database selected, could you please advise.

Comment: Add some error checking in your `connect` function...

Comment: What Shall I add and how shall I add it.

Comment: Please learn from what you did 20 minutes earlier. Use [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). I was willing to help but please make some efforts.

Comment: Shall I put this where it says  mysqli_select_db($con, "DB_DATABASE") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));

Comment: I get an error which says  Unknown database 'db_database'. I have now changed this to be database name and checking if this has solved my problem.

Comment: Now get another error which says that  Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From question comments:

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

The error message says it: in your query, you list a number of columns, and you list a different number of values. Remove `uid` from your columns list (I assume it has `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute).

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->db,"INSERT INTO `users`(`unique_id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `email`, `encrypted_password`, `salt`, `created_at`) VALUES('$uuid', '$fname', '$lname', '$uname', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
```

Comment: Thank you so Much caCtus you have helped me to fix my problem,

Comment: Glad it's finally done! Please accept my answer if it fixed your problem (I'm not used to beg for this but I spent time with you on that one! :D). You should read some stuff about good practices, testing and checking errors. You could have solved this on your own if you had checked errors in the first place. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The sql

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->db, "INSERT INTO users SET (unique_id, firstname, lastname, email, username, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$uname', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
```

is incorrect. It should be

```
INSERT INTO user (unique_id...)
```

Comment: I have now amended it to  $result = mysqli_query($this->db,"INSERT INTO `users`(`uid`, `unique_id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `email`, `encrypted_password`, `salt`, `created_at`) VALUES('$uuid', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$uname', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())"); STILL GETTING SAME ERROR.